# Paypal Express Checkout Error (Method Specified is not Supported)

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I am new to codeigniter and paypal. I am working on gocart(an open source eCommerce solution built on codeIgniter). I try to work on paypal API integrated in it, but its showing error as follows :

```
[ACK] => Failure [L_ERRORCODE0] => 81002 [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Unspecified Method [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Method Specified is not Supported [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
```

Below is my code : paypal_expres.php

```
$this->RETURN_URL = 'www.example.com';
$this->CANCEL_URL = 'www.example.com';
$this->currency = 'USD';
$this->host = "api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com";
$this->gate = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?';


public function doExpressCheckout($amount, $desc, $invoice='') { 
    $data = array( 
      'PAYMENTACTION' =>'Sale',
      'AMT' => '24',
      'RETURNURL' => $this->getReturnTo(),
      'CANCELURL' => $this->getReturnToCancel(),
      'CURRENCYCODE'=> $this->currency,
      'METHOD' => 'SetExpressCheckout'
    ); 
    $query = $this->buildQuery($data);
    $result = $this->response($query);  
    $response = $result->getContent();
    $return = $this->responseParse($response);  
    echo ''; 
    print_r($return);
    echo '';
    if ($return['ACK'] == 'Success') {
        header('Location: '.$this->gate.'cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token='.$return['TOKEN'].''); 
    }
    return($return);
}

public function doExpressCheckout($amount, $desc, $invoice='') {
    $data = array( 
      'PAYMENTACTION' =>'Sale',
      'AMT' => '24',
      'RETURNURL' => $this->getReturnTo(),
      'CANCELURL' => $this->getReturnToCancel(),
      'CURRENCYCODE'=> $this->currency,
      'METHOD' => 'SetExpressCheckout'
    );
    $query = $this->buildQuery($data);
    $result = $this->response($query);
    $response = $result->getContent();
    $return = $this->responseParse($response);
    echo ''; 
    print_r($return);
    echo '';
    if ($return['ACK'] == 'Success') {
        header('Location: '.$this->gate.'cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token='.$return['TOKEN'].'');
        die(); 
    }
    return($return); 
}

private function response($data) {
    $result = $this->CI->httprequest->connect($data);
    if ($result<400) return $this->CI->httprequest;
    return false;
}
private function buildQuery($data = array()) {
    $data['USER'] = $this->API_USERNAME;
    $data['PWD'] = $this->API_PASSWORD;
    $data['SIGNATURE'] = $this->API_SIGNATURE; 
    $data['VERSION'] = '56.0';
    $query = http_build_query($data);
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Typically this error is generated when you are not passing over a valid method, but can be caused by other things not being passed over correctly.  Can you provide your API request string that you are sending over, minus your API credentials.

Comment: As I am hitting request manually, then it comes success. Request is : https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?PAYMENTACTION=Sale&AMT=24&RETURNURL=http://182.18.165.252/eshop&CANCELURL=http://182.18.165.252/eshop&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&USER=xxx&PWD=xxxx&SIGNATURE=xxxx&VERSION=56.0

Comment: Can you provide your string as part of your question post.  I can't see the entire link of what you are sending over due to how it is being displayed in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

When Paypal returns this message it's a case of transmit method, not the method argument/property.

As in Paypal only accepts POST.